# Are Verilog reals synthesisable?

Tags: verilog

Is the Verilog `real` data type synthesisable for a generic Xilinx FPGA? If not, what alternatives do I have for real number manipulation in synthesisable Verilog?

Comment: It depends on what tool you're using for synthesis...

Comment: @BenVoigt: I'm using ISE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: **No.**

Your best bet would be to build your own floating-point block. There are open-source examples. While you can make it IEEE754 compatible, there is no need to. It all depends on your application.

Some applications requires the range provided by single/double-precision IEEE754 numbers. However, other applications only require a small range that can be emulated with fixed-point numbers instead.

Answer (score 1):

No, but some FPGAs have a core that works with built-in hardware for floating point. This [Altera white paper](http://www.altera.com/literature/wp/wp-01028.pdf) discusses some details. However you would have to instantiate them; they can't be inferred by ISE or most other tools.